# How to work with numeric probability distribution functions

Tags: r, distribution

I have to calculate the probability distribution function of a random variable that is composed of (sum, division, product, exponentiation, etc...) some other simple random variables. It is pretty complex so I am morte then happy to get a numerical solution

While  thought this was a very standard thing to do , I was unable to find a framework to do that. I'd preferably use R, but any major language will do.
What I would like therefore is a library that allowed me to:

i) create numerical random variables from classic distributions
ii) compose them by simple operations (+,-,*,/, exp,min, max,...)

Of course I could work with vectors and use convolutions and the like, but I wanted something more polished.

I am also aware that is possible to use simulation to create the variables, then compose them with the operations and finally getting the PDF using a histogram, but again, I would prefer a non - simulating approach.

Comment: thanks! it is really very nice, but is simulation based. I'd prefer something that gave me some sort of guarantee about the precision of the results, but it is indeed very nice. If you answer I'll accept. Unfortunately it does not have the distribution I need built-in(Gumbel), but it is a minor inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the rv package.  Note that if X is an exponential random variable with mean 1, then -log(X) has a standard Gumbel distribution.